# Azure Cosmos Posting a File to use in a Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Hello I am trying to pull data from my cosmos database and then modify it and then send it out to a user through an email which has an attachment of a tab delimited text document of the data.

So far I have the logic app set up to recieve the data and the query to get the data and the method to change the data into the format I want. I need to figure out a way to create a tab delimited file and send that to my logic app. I am only able to get a string to get sent to my logic app of all the data.
Here is the code I am working with:

```
string query = $"Select * from c";
        var restrictions = await _cosmosService.QueryItemsAsync<Data>(Database, query);

        if (restrictions == null)
            return new NoContentResult();
        string tabDelimitedText = ConvertToTabDelimited(restrictions);

        byte[] tabDelimitedBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tabDelimitedText);

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(tabDelimitedBytes);
        var rtn = new FileStreamResult(stream, "text/plain");

        await _client.PostAsync(EmailTriggerUrl, new StringContent(rtn, Encoding.UTF8, "application/text"));
        return rtn;

private string GetTabDelimitedText(List<Person> people)
    {
        StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();
        textWriter.WriteLine("Name\tAge\tCity");
        foreach (var person in people)
        {
            textWriter.WriteLine($"{person.Name}\t{person.Age}\t{person.City}");
        }
        return textWriter.ToString();
    }
```

I know that I need to change the PostAsync from a StringContent but I am unsure what is needs to be

Comment: so, where is the problem? I don't see any questions

Comment: @RomanMarusyk The question is how do I make a tab delimited .txt file from the data in my cosmos db and then send that file to an Azure Logic app to send an email with it? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to pull data from my cosmos database and then modify it and then send it out to a user through an email.

- I extracted data from Cosmos Db using `cosmosClient` and stored it as a `Delimited-Text` file in the Blob container using the below code. Then I used **Logic Apps** to send a mail.

**Below are the steps I followed:**

- `cosmosDbEP`  and  `cosmosDbKey`  are created an instance called  `cosmosClient`  which is used to interact with the Cosmos DB.  `query`  is used to retrieve data from the db.
- `blobServClient`  is created using  `blobConnStr`  which is used to interact with the Azure Blob Storage account.
- `GetTabDelimitedText` method takes a `Data` as parameter. It uses string interpolation to create a string  where data is seperated by tabs `\t`.
- `blobName`  is used to generate a unique blob name for each and every item in cosmos db and `tab-delimited` data is uploaded to Blob storage as a text file.

**Below is the code I tried with:**

```cs
CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(cosmosDbEP, cosmosDbKey);
var cont = cosmosClient.GetContainer(dbId, contId);
var query = new QueryDefinition("SELECT * FROM c");
var queryIterator = cont.GetItemQueryIterator<Data>(query);

BlobServiceClient blobServClient = new BlobServiceClient(blobConnStr);
BlobContainerClient contClient = blobServClient.GetBlobContainerClient(blobContName);

while (queryIterator.HasMoreResults)
{
    var response = await queryIterator.ReadNextAsync();

    foreach (var item in response)
    {
        string tabDelimitedContent = GetTabDelimitedText(item); 

        string blobName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".txt";

        BlobClient blobClient = contClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

        using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tabDelimitedContent)))
        {
            await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, new BlobUploadOptions { HttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "text/plain" } });
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Uploaded item to Blob Storage: {blobName}");
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Data transfer completed.");
```

**Output:**

```
Uploaded item to Blob Storage: 8ee63e0d-cc6d-47b6-ad69-af40097c9134.json
Uploaded item to Blob Storage: 5f24d20c-baff-4f43-a226-e784d333ac72.json
Uploaded item to Blob Storage: 52f0fc8c-6ab8-412b-a700-d36f7ba3aae8.json
Uploaded item to Blob Storage: ca9f2958-0a2c-4eae-9734-605490ccad3d.json
Uploaded item to Blob Storage: e97888ca-3ef2-4c8e-994c-369cd01ad24b.json
Data transfer completed.
```

**Data stored in Blob:**

```
1   Balaji  23  Male
2   Pavan   20  Male
3   Likitha 24  Female
4   Sai 24  Female
5   Venkatesh   25  Male
```

**Design in Logic Apps:**

- In **Logic Apps** the data which is stored in Blob container is added by mentioning container name `/tbalaji`. Now, the data can be sent to mail in Logic Apps as you can see below.

[image]